# Is it possible that the way Rust creates threads doesn't play nicely with the C library's dependence on pthreads?

Tags: linux, rust, pthreads

I am trying to use a C library in Rust by creating bindings automatically with bindgen.  Using these bindings, I write a Rust API so that Rust developers can use the C library with a nice Rust API.  Everything works great until threads are involved, at which points I experience race conditions and deadlocks.

The C library was written with thread-safety in mind and relies heavily on `pthread_setspecific` and `pthread_getspecific` for thread-local storage.  I think it is possible the race conditions and deadlocks are caused by the code related to the thread-local machinations of the C library.

Is it possible that the way Rust is creating threads doesn't play nicely with the C library's dependence on pthreads and that this incompatibility is causing the issues I am seeing?

I don't know a lot about Linux threads, though I have spent some time reading up about it in connection to this problem.

Comment: It's pretty hard to answer this without seeing some code. For starters, how are you spawning threads in Rust? Or is the Rust code single-threaded but the C library is multi-threaded?

Comment: If the C library is depending on thread-local storage and expects to be called in its own pthread then that could certainly cause a problem. I'm not sure of the quality, but I found this: https://github.com/mahkoh/posix.rs which might help.

Comment: @PeterHall I'll grant you that, but it would be hard for me to show code because there are so many relevant layers.

The Rust code is multi-threaded and the C code is aware that it might be called in a multi-threaded context so therefore uses thread-local storage for certain structures via pthreads_getspecefic and pthreads_setspecific.

Comment: @PeterHall based on some poking around, it looks like Rust std::thread relies on pthreads.  If that is in fact the case, *should* Rust be able to call to arbitrary C code that uses pthreads_[set, get]specific and expect the correct result?